# How I can count elements of a column?

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I am wondering how I can count elements of each row?

I have the following column:

```
Column
(‘a’, ‘b’),(‘a’, ‘c’),(‘b’, ‘c’)
(‘g’, ‘h’),(‘a’, ‘c’),(‘a’, ‘b’)
```

I wanna count how many of the above pair exist in the data set!

```
Output:
(‘a’, ‘b’)  2
(‘a’, ‘c’). 2
(‘b’, ‘c’).  1
(‘g’, ‘h’).  1
```

Comment: I would just use `df.explode` to all the column data and then use that column to get the `value_counts()`.

Comment: please provide a non ambiguous example? the quotes you used are not valid python, so it's unclear whether you have a string or lists of tuples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `findall` to extract tuple and `explode` to separate them. Finally, use `value_counts` to count occurrences:

```
>>> df.Column.str.findall(r'(\([^()]+\))').explode().value_counts()

(‘a’, ‘b’)    2
(‘a’, ‘c’)    2
(‘b’, ‘c’)    1
(‘g’, ‘h’)    1
Name: Column, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know how I can sort tuple before counting them? For an example if I have (‘summer’, ‘book’) , the sorted one is (‘book’, ‘summer’)! (Alphabetically order)

Comment: Please check @mozway comment about your quotes.If you have normal ones, it's pretty easy to use`pd.eval` and sort tuples. I will update my answer according your answer.